# $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ extension of a local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-groups, local-fields, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $G$ be an arbitrary open group of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Can we construct a Galois extension field $E$ of $K$ such that $\text{Gal}(E/K)\cong G$? This is a special case of $p$-adic Lie group extensions of $K$, cf. [1](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/laurent.berger/articles/article26.pdf).

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: A trivial remark: at least the image of $G$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has to be solvable.

Comment: @Aurel Could you explain how you deduce this? Thanks!

Comment: Galois extensions of local fields are solvable (this follows from the inertia filtration)